# MySQL SELECT multiple tables and select date and compare to date today

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to select the date on my database and compare it to the date today. My current code has no error but it doesn't give me any result.

My code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select *, date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') from appointment
                                LEFT JOIN doctor
                                ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.appointment_title
                                LEFT JOIN patient
                                ON patient.patient_id = appointment.patient_id
                                where appointment.appointment_title = $session_id AND
                                date(appointment.date) = CURDATE()
                                order by appointment.date ASC");
```

EDIT:

Here's an example of appointment.date = `03/05/2018` and the data type is var

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in your query.  You might want to show us some sample data along with what output you are expecting.

Comment: can you provide an example of  `appointment.date`

Comment: i edited my post with example of appointment.date

Comment: ahh well that's the problem, you need to store dates, as um,  dates (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: is that the only problem? im storing the dates in wrong data type?

Comment: cant see any others, but also can't see the full db schema or data

Comment: thanks! i already change the data type and there is now result. thanks

Comment: Don’t know about mysql, but in db2 the asterisk without designating the table would be an error. Also, possible wrong field in ‘on doctor.doctor_id=appointment.appointment_*title*’?  Also, I see the same issue in your where clause.  Assuming that your title is not just an Id number, that would prevent any results ;)

Comment: Nm, didn’t see you fixed it

Comment: Please note that the date format for MySQL is an ISO standard that resolves any ambiguity such as D/M/Y vs M/D/Y. One expected format is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `STR_TO_DATE()` function to convert date according to current date format

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM appointment
                            LEFT JOIN doctor
                            ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.appointment_title
                            LEFT JOIN patient
                            ON patient.patient_id = appointment.patient_id
                            WHERE appointment.appointment_title = $session_id AND
                            date(STR_TO_DATE(appointment.date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = CURDATE()
                            ORDER BY appointment.date ASC");
```

Answer (score -1):

By using CURDATE() you have something like : **20180306**.
Try this one :

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select *, date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') from appointment
                                LEFT JOIN doctor
                                ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.appointment_title
                                LEFT JOIN patient
                                ON patient.patient_id = appointment.patient_id
                                where appointment.appointment_title = $session_id AND
                                date(appointment.date) = DATE(CURDATE())
                                order by appointment.date ASC");
```

Comment: Perhaps the non result comes from the syntaxe of the join. 
I'm not sure so, just try